# why ffmpeg trimming videos while converting to m3u8?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-streaming

I am using ffmpeg version 3.2.2, and converting mp4 and mov files to m3u8 format by below command.

```
ffmpeg -i test.mov output.m3u8
```

The length of test.mov is around 3 min, but it convert it to last 24-25 seconds of only, when I play that m3u8 in player. I even merge all the segments of m3u8 to confirm the length of video, by command

```
ffmpeg -i output.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

the output.mp4 is also 24-25 sec, the last 24 seconds of test.mov.

I don't know what is wrong, it is working with small length input files like 10 seconds file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the HLS muxer only keeps the last 5 segments in the playlist.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i test.mov -hls_list_size 0 output.m3u8
```